# Meaning of 'Within 24 hours they will be shown for a & b times respectively' in this problem:

Tags: meaning, prepositions, time

In a movie theatre two movies 'Avengers' and 'Inception' with running time of 3 & 4 hours respectively and ticket price of 15$ & 25$ respectively will be shown. **Within 24 hours they will be shown for a & b times** respectively such that a,b >= 1. What will be the value of a+b so that the theatre owner make the maximum profit out of it? 
My confusion: 
**Here is it necessay to keep the theatre running for all 24 hours or it can be closed before 24 hours if the owner can make maximum profit??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO,
**"a"**(shows of Avengers (15$/show)) must be **1** and **"b"**(shows of Inception(25$/show)) must be **5**.i.e.

**1 * 3 hrs = 3** hrs per day for Avengers, where as 
 **5 * 4 hrs = 20** hrs per day for Inception
 hence total running hrs will be **3 + 20 = 23**,

Total Daily collection **= (15*1) + (25*5) = 140$**


So answer to your question is **6 shows per day** so that the theatre owner make the maximum profit.

Comment: Yes I've got the similar answer so it is not a problem if we close before 24 hours right?